# gtkmm text on a picture

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'd like to have a picture element in my gui with text on it. My goal is to load pictures (for example a waterdrop) and place text on it which stands for a measured humidity (values come from MQTT).

What would be the best way to do this? I don't care if it's a label or any other kind of element (though I'm not happy with misusing a button for that). The text needs to be changable. Im very new to this framework so I didn't get the hang on it yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to use a [Gtk::TextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextView.html) ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I havent. How would I go with it? Using ``drag_set_as_icon``?

Comment: Read http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/gtkwidgets/

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ill do, thank you

Comment: @ThomasSablik Im sorry, Im still not sure how to do it. Could you give me another hint? A method I need to call or something?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? There is example code for labels and other widgets.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I cant see anything referencing an image or icon into the label or other widgets. The only shown widget which is related to pictures is an IconView and thats not what Im looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example code. It uses an overlay to stack two widgets, an image and a label:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *image;
  GtkWidget *label;
  GtkWidget *overlay;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Sandbox");

  image = gtk_image_new_from_file("image.png");
  label = gtk_label_new("I've always been too lame\n\
To see what's before me\n\
And I know nothing sweeter than\n\
Champaign from last New Years\n\
Sweet music in my ears\n\
And a night full of no fears\n\
\n\
But if I had one wish fulfilled tonight\n\
I'd ask for the sun to never rise\n\
If God passed a mic to me to speak\n\
I'd say \"Stay in bed, world,\n\
Sleep in peace");

  overlay = gtk_overlay_new ();

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), overlay);

  gtk_overlay_add_overlay(GTK_OVERLAY(overlay), image);
  gtk_overlay_add_overlay(GTK_OVERLAY(overlay), label);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution (well, the equivalent in gtkmm) but I get the error "Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type gtkmm__GtkLabel to a gtkmm_GtkOverlay, but as GtkBin subclass a gtkmm_GtkOverlay can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type gtkmm_GtkImage"

Comment: I recommend to ask a new, more specific question with a [mcve] of your source code. This question was to broad.

Comment: I found an error in my code as I didnt transfer your code correctly. Thank you so much for providing the answer, this problem bothered me for several days now.